# Events, callbacks or listeners in Go on Raspberry pi gpio lines?

Tags: events, go, interrupt, raspberry-pi2

I've used Go successfully to read weather station data though USB and compose web pages. I want to ditch the 'console' and read the instruments directly, which is straightforward for temp and pressure but I can't bring myself to poll the anemometer input with a busy waiting loop. Hiding the busy wait in a thread is, well, just hiding it. Is there an actual interrupt mechanism?

(The anemometer is a simple reed relay that closes once per rev).

Comment: This is not an answer but might help.  There is a C library named WiringPi that handles edge-triggered interrupts.  Possibly you can make interrupts work in Go.  https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/functions/

Comment: Actually, C will do. I will give it a try Chad